# .bib file stopped refreshing from Zotero

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf, zotero

I have linked my Zotero with my Overleaf document and have had no problems to date. I used to be able to refresh the imported `.bib` file when I would update my Zotero with new references, however this has stopped working and is no longer allowing me to refresh it.

I haven't changed anything to do with how this was set up so I was wondering if other people are having this issue or if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: This rather looks like an issue which should be reported to the Overleaf support.

Comment: Hi isobel, Tom from Overleaf Support here. Can you please try unlinking your Zotero account (from Overleaf -> Account -> Account Settings) and re-linking it. And if it doesn't help, reach to me via support@overleaf.com so that we can have a look at the possible sources of the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Overleaf-specific issues should be addressed to the Overleaf Helpdesk , via email to support@overleaf.com. Overleaf's LaTeX support team is top-notch.

Comment: Hi Tom - thanks for the advice, that has fixed it for me! In future I'll make sure I use the support@overleaf.com for Overleaf-specific issues.